# Parsing Microsoft ODC file to connect to SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel

I have an Excel workbook that I inherited and it refreshes data from an external data source. The connection string is:

```
DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=XXXXXX;UID=XXXXXX;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=XXXXXX;DATABASE=XXXXXXXX;Network=XXXXXX
```

Can I use this information or the ODC file to connect to the database to query the table within?

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, your current excel work book has an external data source, which is a SQL Server.  If that is the case, then yes, you can utilize the same credentials in the connection string.  In your case, the "Trusted Connection=Yes" means your actually using your Windows login credentials.  To connect to the database, query data directly, you can use either SQL Server Management Studio, SQLCMD or any other SQL Server supported query tool to connect.  Take the SERVER=XXXXXX value as the server name, and use Windows Authentication.  You many also want to set the database to match as well.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to use Microsoft Access to access the database using ODBC and SQL Server, but I never got the option to enter the database name. It listed a bunch of tables that seemed very generic and not the table I needed.